# Interlocking Two Strings in Python ProblemSetQuestion (Self-Taught)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Winkleson here! I am currently learning Python when I got stuck on a problem. I've gotten to the point where I'm dizzy just thinking about it :P Anyways any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Question:

---

> **Interlock**
>
> Create a function that takes two strings that are the same
> length or within one character of the same length as parameters. It
> should then take these two strings and interlock them, taking one
> character from each string, interlocking them. If the strings are
> different lengths, then the result should always start with the longer
> string.

My Coding (sorry I'm a beginner and it's not very Pythonic :P):

---

```
def interlock(s1, s2):
    
    r = 0
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    inters = ''
    
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        
            l1.append(i)
        
    for i in range(len(s2)):
              
            l2.append(i)
    
    if len(s2) == len(s1):        
        
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            inters += ''.join(s1[i])
            inters += ''.join(s2[i])                
    
    elif len(s1) < len(s2):
        
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            inters += ''.join(s2[i])
            inters += ''.join(s1[i])
            r = i
            
        inters += ''.join(s2[r])
            
    elif len(s2) < len(s1):
        
        for i in range(len(s2)):
            inters += ''.join(s1[i])
            inters += ''.join(s2[i])
            r = i
        
        inters += ''.join(s1[r])
        
    else:
        pass
    
    return inters
```

Results (what results I recieve):

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________

 Call                   Expected    Received    Correct

 interlock('shoe','cold')   schooled    schooled    true

 interlock('flat','etry')   feltarty    feltarty    true

 **interlock('ab','siy')    saiby           saibi           false**

 **interlock('abalone','hammer')    ahbaamlmoenre   ahbaamlmoenrn   false**

 interlock('','a')          a           a           true

___________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The two bolder fields are where I am having the most issues. If I try to add in the last characters I get a mysterious out of range exception. Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated! - Winkleson

P.s This is shorter than my normal posts... Usually I'll give an (un)accurate idea on what I'm think I'm doing wrong and it drags on and on and on and on.... you get the idea. Anyways I probably broke my loops like an idiot. So... Goodluck!

**THANKS**

Thank you everyone who suggested ways to become a better programmer! I don't get much time in a day to program so it's great when so many people take time out of their day to suggest stuff. I love this website and it's community :)

Comment: A few comments.  `join` is unnecessary here.  You could just do `inters += s1[i]`, etc.  Also, to break a string into a list is as easy as `list(s1)`

Comment: I really want to answer `''.join(itertools.chain(*zip(s1, s2)))`, but that doesn't meet your requirements.  :(  What a shame.

Comment: @cdhowie -- `izip_longest(s1,s2,fill_value='')` ;-)

Comment: Also, I think you want to start with `r = 1` and use `r = i+1`.

Comment: @mgilson So close, though that doesn't handle which string to start with correctly.  But a small comparison should sort that out.

Comment: is this actually interleaving? I'm amiss at to what the purpose of this is :( [maybe I'm just tired]

Comment: @cdhowie -- I suppose you coudld pass `sorted((s1,s2),key=len)` to order them... or maybe reversed of that...

Comment: @mgilson I know how to use lists (There are actually two useless ones created when I was messing around with them earlier in my code but decided just to skip it. Thanks for pointing out the join() bit though. I tend to overdoit with that call :P Furthermore if I start with r = 1 I will miss the strings first character.

Comment: @Winkleson Just my two cents. I would [*refactor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) the string manipulation from the decision tree logic into two functions.  Create a generic `interlock` function that puts together two strings, regardless of length; and then make a function that 'feeds' it by ensuring that the two strings are in the right order/are of the right length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While others are showing you how to do this using itertools (which is a very useful exercise), this will hopefully demonstrate how to write your function to help you learn some basic programming:

```
def interlock(s1, s2):

    r = 1
    l1 = list(s1)
    l2 = list(s2)
    inters = ''
    if len(s2) == len(s1):        
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            inters += s1[i]
            inters += s2[i]

    elif len(s1) < len(s2):
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            inters += s2[i]
            inters += s1[i]
            r = i+1
        inters += s2[r]

    elif len(s2) < len(s1):
        for i in range(len(s2)):
            inters += s1[i]
            inters += s2[i]
            r = i+1

        inters += s1[r]

    else:
        pass

    return inters


a = interlock('abalone','hammer')
print (a)
print (a[::2])
print (a[1::2])
a = interlock('hammer','abalone')
print (a)
print (a[::2])
print (a[1::2])
a = interlock('ab','siy')
print (a)
```

I've purposefully kept a lot of the structure from your original code, only removing the pieces which are completely unnecessary (e.g. your excessive use of `str.join`).

Comment: Thankyou. This is exactly what I was looking for :P However, I suppose I should start looking into the more complicated modules. One thing I don't understand is why defining r within the for loop worked while just adding a position change of +1 did not. Any particular reason?

Comment: @Winkleson I wouldn't say that any of the other solutions introduce more "complicated" modules. They're using tried and tested solutions - would you write your own btree anymore, or write your "+" operator at machine code level, but yes - best not forget that while using Python we are spoilt on all levels and someone somewhere should still know these :) +1 mgilson - as always ;)

Comment: Also... Yes I get a bit excessive when coding... I tend to do extra when I really can do a simple function (IE: Attaching every char to the lists instead of just declaring the lists as list of the string...).

Comment: @Winkleson Your code could be much simpler without importing any modules at all.

Comment: @Jon Clements Thanks for the encouragement. Still would be good to tap into the lambda solutions as I find a million of them when looking through already solved question on StackOverflow (Mainly when I need help or want to see if there is an easier solution. Thanks for being a regular on the site by the way!

Comment: @Marcin I didn't import any modules :P I generally mean there is alot more for me to learn out there :) I know the basics (well sortof) and believe I should expand my horizons! Thanks again for your input!

Comment: The key here is that Python contains so much syntatic shortcuts that python code tends to be much smaller than equivalent C code. That's why being "pythonic" is so sought after by python newcomers.

Comment: @Winkleson I know you didn't import any modules. I am telling you that the simplification of your code does not rely primarily on the use of modules, but rather on better programming techniques. You do not know even the basics.

Comment: @Marcin What do you consider "the basics" in this context?

Comment: @Marcin .... I know that? I didn't even mention any modules except for lambda :P I was just saying that it would be good to learn lambda due to all the code out there that is in association with it. However I do need to look into more programming techniques as well.

Comment: @Winkleson Lambda is not a module.

Comment: @Marcin http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk I was looking at this at the time. I'm sorry I was incorrect. Thanks again for your suggestions. Not to happy about the -1 though XD

Comment: @Jon Clements Thanks again for your help/support!

Comment: @Winkleson Don't blame that article for your error. It does not show a separate lambda module.

Comment: @Marcin It is my error, I just saw the function bit and made a bad assumption in believing it needed to be imported like the math module. Sorry that dislike me but that doesn't give you the right to force your views. Especially as I don't yet understand that style of programming.

Comment: @Winkleson I'm not forcing my views on you, unless you consider yourself entitled to your own facts.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could be shortened, but I think this is fairly pythonic without being too much pythonic, besides it doesn't use too much black magic, and no imports:

```
def interlock(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1

    s1, s2 = map(list, [s1, s2])
    for i in xrange(len(s2)):
        s1.insert((2*i+1), s2[i])
    print ''.join(s1)
```

Now some Python teaching:

- `s1, s2 = s2, s1` is a very pythonic way to swap two variables. I used it to be sure that `s1` is the longest string;
- `map` is used to map the function `list()` to the list of strings `[s1, s2]`, converting them to lists of single character strings;
- `insert` is a list method (strings don't have it) used to insert an item in the middle of a sequence, at a given position;
- The `(2*i + 1)` part is necessary because it's necessary to insert between every other item of `s1`;
- `''.join()` is a string operation, used here to join the resulting list of characters into a single string, using an empty string, or "nothing" (`''`) as a separator or "joining element".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting. If I changed xrange() -> range() would it work in 3.x? Once again not knowing alot of python's Data types hinders my ability to problemsolve again :P

Comment: The only difference between `range` and `xrange` is that the first creates a list first, and then iterates over its elements, while the second creates a generator, and yields one item at a time. This is useful when creating a whole list at first would consume too much memory or processing time, but for shorter examples like this one there is not much practical difference. I believe both would work with this code, but best practices recommend using `xrange` in loops, and that's what you're going to find out in tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown! I am currently just learning things by asking questions, looking up modules and running through problemset questions on http://singpath.appspot.com. ANyways thanks again!

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that `xrange` isn't strictly a generator -- It's an object which is iterable like `range`, but doesn't store a list.  This becomes important because in *a lot* of ways, `xrange` really does behave like a list.  `a = xrange(4); a[3]` is possible (which doesn't fly with generators) -- In other words, `xrange` is like a generator, but it's cooler in most ways -- one drawback is that you can't do `next(xrange(10))` ...

Comment: @mgilson pretty neat :) Thanks for the note! P.s. Generators are like lists but you can only run through the values one at a time... right?

Comment: @Winkleson -- I think that the difference between generators and lists is too broad for me to address in a comment, but they are similar in that both can be iterated over and 1 way they are different is that with a generators are not indexible.

Comment: @mgilson Good to know. My impression was that they were just more complicated lists due to the next func. Anyways I'll probably come across them again in my studies. Thanks again for your valuable answer!

Comment: @heltonbiker I was rereading you post and I realized that you never returned the complete values in the interlocked list. Would all it take to fix this is a statement like: return ''.join(s1) instead of print ''.join(s1)? Sorry for the trouble I'm just intrigued :D

Comment: @Winkleson yeah, I just used print to get you the idea. The good practice is this: if the function should just print, then you end it with a `print(the_result)` and call it like `function()`. Now if you want to use the return value somewhere else and also would like to print it (for debugging, for example), then you should use `return the_result` as the last line of the function, and call it like `some_result = function(); print(some_result)`.

Comment: @heltonbiker Okay I just wanted to be certain that there were no exceptions! I actually just used your example in a seperate problem in which 2 strings would be returned like so: s1,s2,s1 unless len(s1) < len(s2). Normally I would have to do a more complex statement but the s1, s2 = s2, s1 statement really simplified it. Thanks for teaching me the multiple expressions on one operator trick :P Also thanks for the clarification (and your time)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to engage in some data-driven programming:

```
s1,s2 = sorted(("foo","baxer"), key=len, reverse=True)
```

Now, you now that your input has a fixed relationship.

Python also has a number of tools in the `itertools` module which can help you achieve this more easily.

Here's a simplified version of mgilson's code above:

```
def interlock(in1, in2):
    r = 1
    s1,s2 = sorted((in1,in2), key=len, reverse=True)
    inters = ''
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        inters += s2[i]
        inters += s1[i]
        r = i+1
    if r < len(s2):
        inters += s2[r]

    return inters
```

You can see that simply making your data correspond to a particular invariant removes the need for two thirds of the code.

Comment: I would use `key=len, reverse=True`.  Saves a `lambda`

Comment: @Marcin Yeah I not dip into lamda at the present time. I'd rather become very proficent with my loops first. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: @Winkleson Lambda abstraction and iteration are not alternatives. In addition, the point of this is not lambda abstraction, it is that your code should work on data, not be a giant list of cases to handle all possible inputs.

Comment: @Marcin Okay, Okay... I'll give it a try. In the meantime can you point out why the last character for elif1 and elif2 are not printing? And furthermore why s1[r+1] would be out of range if s2 < s1?

Comment: @Winkleson No, because that isn't a part of your question. In any case, those things will fall away when you simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something making use of `itertools`:

```
def interlock(s1, s2):
    if len(s2) > len(s1):
        (s1, s2) = (s2, s1)

    return ''.join(itertools.chain(*itertools.izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue='')))
```

Comment: I don't think this is entirely helpful to a beginner.

Comment: @Marcin Learning how to use a language effectively seems helpful to me.

Comment: Sure, and apple pie is good. It doesn't mean that exhibiting an apple pie makes everyone able to afford apple pies.

Comment: No, but if you give them the recipe, maybe they could make their own.

Comment: This isn't a recipe, this is the pie.

Comment: @cdhowie Marcin is right I don't know itertools at all but apparently it's a priority :P

Comment: In such a contrived example, the pie *is* the recipe.  Unless you are referring to my thought process in coming up with a solution.  This code is inspectable and it's fairly easy to figure out what each piece does and why it's there.

Comment: @cdhowie I think that, some weeks from now, Winkleston would be able to come back and recognize where he was wrong and what is happening with all that `itertools` stuff, but not now. It is very difficult for advanced users to recognize the difficulties faced by absolute beginners, and I can tell this from both sides. Just a thought.

Comment: @heltonbiker *winkleson. However you are completely correct on everything but the grammatical spelling of my name!